# Set var to true if another var is falsy or true but not boolean false

Tags: javascript, variables, boolean

I want to set a `variable` to `true` if it is anything but boolean `false`

Example:

`undefined, null, 0, "", NaN, true, etc = true, otherwise false`

I have a function that accepts one argument and unless it's set to boolean `false` then I want to make it `true`.

I feel like this should be a simple one-liner but I cannot seem to figure it out.

I must be over-complicating things.

Comment: sorry about the edit, I had an attack of "var is falsy[.]", when you clearly say "var is falsy or true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `!==` which checks both value and type

```
function myMethod(parameter){
    parameter = parameter !== false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell me what would this return `parameter = parameter !== false;` if the parameter value is `undefined` ? and what this other one return `parameter !== false ? true : false` .. even if the operator is `!=` it is the same

Comment: @JEES: `undefined` and `false` are different types, so `!==` would be `true` because they are not strictly equal. (You can, of course, check this trivially using your browser's web console by typing `undefined !== false` and seeing what it shows you.)

Comment: @T.J, correct me please if i am wrong, but the first one would return `parameter` ? and the later returns `true` as long as the parameter is not `false`. am I wrong?

Comment: @JEES: The first one does not return `parameter` because of `!==`

Comment: @JEES, when you say `parameter = parameter !== false;` there is no *returning* happening in this statement. Rather, you are saying *whatever is the result of* `parameter !== false` *store that result in the variable* `parameter`

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `!==` operator

```
 var isGood = (x !== false);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just check the parameter with false as following:

```
var myVar = (parameter !== false);
```